I'm writing my thesis and I want to number the figures and tables of a certain section with roman numbers and the rest with numbers
I'm using an overleaf template link (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/thesis-template-faculty-of-engineering-ain-shams-university/ykvrxppdjqmz) to write my thesis and I wanted to number the tables and figures with roman numerals in the introduction, then begin the chapters' figures and tables counting in numbers 1,2,3 ..
the document source ( https://www.overleaf.com/project/666c14a6ed40dabe29500fbf)
How can you number a section alone, apart from the rest of the thesis, in Roman numbers?
like this

the first tables are included in the introduction, while the rest are in the chapters
This is the main.tex

\documentclass[12pt, twoside,openright]{Thesis} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{float}

\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\input{Chapters/Introduction}
\input{Chapters/Chapter1} 
\end{document}  

These are for the thesis sections

% Introduction

\chapter{Introduction} 
\label{Introduction} 
\lhead{Introduction} 

\setcounter{figure}{0}



\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=14cm]{Figures/glyapp.png}
    \caption{Versatile application of glycerol }
    \label{glycerolapp}
\end{figure} 



% Chapter 1

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\label{Chapter1} 
\lhead{Chapter 1.} 


\setcounter{figure}{0}



\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=14cm]{Figures/glyapp.png}
    \caption{Versatile application of glycerol }
    \label{glycerolapp}
\end{figure} 


I managed to make the figures begin from 1 then 2 and so on.. in chapter 1
But I can't number the figure in the introduction by roman numerals

Please include a compilable test document in your question.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz , like this you mean ( https://www.overleaf.com/project/666c14a6ed40dabe29500fbf)

Please include it in your question, not as link. This will ensure that your question remains useful to future users even if the link stops working.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you for the advice ^^

As samcarter already told: Please add a compilable test document in your question not as link.

@cabohah i adjusted it, I hope it's better and easier to help me with this version

Not really (see my link). However, try \renewcomman*{\thefigure}{\Roman{figure}} and similar for table. For Arabic numbering use \arabic{…} instead of \Roman{…}.

@cabohah, I'll check the link, thank you alot
